# Factorization of Quartic Polynomial

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots, factoring

I am stuck with this elementary algebra problem.It asks to find the factorization of the following quartic polynomial.

> $x^4-3x-2$

Clearly this polynomial contains no rational root by Rational Root Theorem. From the graph plotted in $Desmos$ I saw that it contains two real roots.Then this polynomial can be factored non-trivially in two quadratic polynomials. But what is the factorization? I failed to find it.

Comment: Do you know about the resolvent cubic?  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ResolventCubic.html.  You get a factorization if the resolvent cubic has a rational root, which this one does.

Comment: @OscarLanzi how to find this factorization?

Comment: @OscarLanzi can you give me a complete solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Since the polynomial is monic and has integer coefficients, any quadratic factorization into rational polynomials must be of the form
$$x^4 - 3 x - 2 = (x^2 + a_1 x + a_0)(x^2 + b_1 x + b_0).$$
Expanding and comparing constant terms gives $a_0 b_0 = -2$, so one of $a_0, b_0$ is $\pm 2$ and the other is (respectively) $\mp 1$. By relabeling, we may as well take $a_0 = \pm 2$. For each of those possibilities, try to solve for $a_1, b_1$.

Comment: can we find integer solutions to $a_1,b_1,a_0,b_0$?

Comment: What happens when you try to do so, using the simplification pointed out in the answer?

Comment: please write a complete solution

Comment: You'll find that most people here are reluctant to do your homework for you. The answer already shows you how to reduce the problem to solving some easy equations.